# Tailwindcss how to create star rating

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

i try create star rating in tailwindcss,
I only know that I have to use 'peer' and 'group' class

```
<div class="text-center">
  <span class="flex flex-row-reverse">
    <i class='peer'>start icon 1</i>
    <i class='peer'>start icon 2</i>
    <i class='peer'>start icon 3</i>
    <i class='peer'>start icon 4</i>
    <i class='peer'>start icon 5</i>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Honestly this seems like you want someone to do 99% of the thinking for you. You should at least provide a serious try.

Comment: To make the front part of the Google schema rating, whene hove star item colored befor star item and self star

Answer (score 4):

You may use `peer-hover` modifier to achieve such result

```html
<div class="flex flex-row-reverse justify-center p-10">
  <i class="bg-yellow-100 peer peer-hover:bg-yellow-500 hover:bg-yellow-500 w-12 h-12 mx-2">1</i>
  <i class="bg-yellow-100 peer peer-hover:bg-yellow-500 hover:bg-yellow-500 w-12 h-12 mx-2">2</i>
  <i class="bg-yellow-100 peer peer-hover:bg-yellow-500 hover:bg-yellow-500 w-12 h-12 mx-2">3</i> 
  <i class="bg-yellow-100 peer peer-hover:bg-yellow-500 hover:bg-yellow-500 w-12 h-12 mx-2">4</i> 
  <i class="bg-yellow-100 peer peer-hover:bg-yellow-500 hover:bg-yellow-500 w-12 h-12 mx-2">5</i> 
</div>
```

[DEMO](https://play.tailwindcss.com/Dg4jL3gIsJ)

`peer peer-hover:bg-yellow-500` will color all next neighbours but not hovered element itself while - that is why you need `hover:bg-yellow-500`. In order to color previous element use little trick - reverse flex row or set `dir="rtl"` attribute on a parent element

NOTE: all your stars will be reversed

Comment: Thank you, this code is better for me because it is short or doesn't need to create a function, and it works perfectly, of course, I little changed it and I will put it here for other users.

Comment: Very clever, I thought about using peer but I didn't think about ordering the stars in reverse to make it possible.

Answer (score 0):

you can use css to create customs class in tailwind

```
//tailwind.config

plugins: [
    function ({ addVariant }) {
      addVariant('stars-rating', '& i:hover ~ i')
    },
    function ({ addVariant }) {
      addVariant('current-hover', '& i:hover')
    },
  ],
```

the first function is to color the previous stars where you hover, the second one is to give color the current star

and the html

```
<div class="stars-rating:bg-yellow-400 current-hover:bg-yellow-400 flex h-screen w-screen flex-row-reverse items-center justify-center bg-slate-500">
  <i class="mx-1 rounded-full border border-yellow-400 p-1">start</i>
  <i class="mx-1 rounded-full border border-yellow-400 p-1">start</i>
  <i class="mx-1 rounded-full border border-yellow-400 p-1">start</i>
  <i class="mx-1 rounded-full border border-yellow-400 p-1">start</i>
  <i class="mx-1 rounded-full border border-yellow-400 p-1">start</i>
</div>
```

you can see the example: [enter link description here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/XfLSgtfrGc)

Comment: Thank you so much
I will test and find the answer here

Comment: Any idea how to make the star you clicked permanent?

Answer (score 0):

The code I use is as follows

```
  <div class="text-center">
    <span class="flex flex-row-reverse">

      <svg class="text-gray-600 cursor-pointer peer peer-hover:text-yellow-400 hover:text-yellow-400 duration-100 " width="23" height="23" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M11.049 2.927c.3-.921 1.603-.921 1.902 0l1.519 4.674a1 1 0 00.95.69h4.915c.969 0 1.371 1.24.588 1.81l-3.976 2.888a1 1 0 00-.363 1.118l1.518 4.674c.3.922-.755 1.688-1.538 1.118l-3.976-2.888a1 1 0 00-1.176 0l-3.976 2.888c-.783.57-1.838-.197-1.538-1.118l1.518-4.674a1 1 0 00-.363-1.118l-3.976-2.888c-.784-.57-.38-1.81.588-1.81h4.914a1 1 0 00.951-.69l1.519-4.674z"></path>
      </svg>

      <svg class="text-gray-600 cursor-pointer peer peer-hover:text-yellow-400 hover:text-yellow-400 duration-100 " width="23" height="23" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M11.049 2.927c.3-.921 1.603-.921 1.902 0l1.519 4.674a1 1 0 00.95.69h4.915c.969 0 1.371 1.24.588 1.81l-3.976 2.888a1 1 0 00-.363 1.118l1.518 4.674c.3.922-.755 1.688-1.538 1.118l-3.976-2.888a1 1 0 00-1.176 0l-3.976 2.888c-.783.57-1.838-.197-1.538-1.118l1.518-4.674a1 1 0 00-.363-1.118l-3.976-2.888c-.784-.57-.38-1.81.588-1.81h4.914a1 1 0 00.951-.69l1.519-4.674z"></path>
      </svg>

      <svg class="text-gray-600 cursor-pointer peer peer-hover:text-yellow-400 hover:text-yellow-400 duration-100 " width="23" height="23" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M11.049 2.927c.3-.921 1.603-.921 1.902 0l1.519 4.674a1 1 0 00.95.69h4.915c.969 0 1.371 1.24.588 1.81l-3.976 2.888a1 1 0 00-.363 1.118l1.518 4.674c.3.922-.755 1.688-1.538 1.118l-3.976-2.888a1 1 0 00-1.176 0l-3.976 2.888c-.783.57-1.838-.197-1.538-1.118l1.518-4.674a1 1 0 00-.363-1.118l-3.976-2.888c-.784-.57-.38-1.81.588-1.81h4.914a1 1 0 00.951-.69l1.519-4.674z"></path>
      </svg>

      <svg class="text-gray-600 cursor-pointer peer peer-hover:text-yellow-400 hover:text-yellow-400 duration-100 " width="23" height="23" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M11.049 2.927c.3-.921 1.603-.921 1.902 0l1.519 4.674a1 1 0 00.95.69h4.915c.969 0 1.371 1.24.588 1.81l-3.976 2.888a1 1 0 00-.363 1.118l1.518 4.674c.3.922-.755 1.688-1.538 1.118l-3.976-2.888a1 1 0 00-1.176 0l-3.976 2.888c-.783.57-1.838-.197-1.538-1.118l1.518-4.674a1 1 0 00-.363-1.118l-3.976-2.888c-.784-.57-.38-1.81.588-1.81h4.914a1 1 0 00.951-.69l1.519-4.674z"></path>
      </svg>

      <svg class="text-gray-600 cursor-pointer peer peer-hover:text-yellow-400 hover:text-yellow-400 duration-100 " width="23" height="23" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M11.049 2.927c.3-.921 1.603-.921 1.902 0l1.519 4.674a1 1 0 00.95.69h4.915c.969 0 1.371 1.24.588 1.81l-3.976 2.888a1 1 0 00-.363 1.118l1.518 4.674c.3.922-.755 1.688-1.538 1.118l-3.976-2.888a1 1 0 00-1.176 0l-3.976 2.888c-.783.57-1.838-.197-1.538-1.118l1.518-4.674a1 1 0 00-.363-1.118l-3.976-2.888c-.784-.57-.38-1.81.588-1.81h4.914a1 1 0 00.951-.69l1.519-4.674z"></path>
      </svg>
      
    </span>
  </div>
```

You can copy this code and test it in the link below [TEST](https://play.tailwindcss.com/)